# MATLAB - Using bins to create PDF of sin wave

Tags: matlab

Basically, I have a complicated function which I have simplified to a sin wave in order to check if my code is working. My task is to create the pdf of the function without using the MATLAB pdf function. What I am trying to do is starting with the minimum value in each array the algorithm steps through array in set steps to create bins and determine the amount of values in the array which fall within that bin.I tried using an example i found online which makes sense but does not seem to be working for me. Here is my code:

```
clear all
clc
A  = 1;
E  = 1;
a1 = 0;
a2 = 0;
a3 = 0;
w  = pi;
y  = 0;
% ts = .1;
% t  = 0:ts:10;
t  = -1:0.01:1;
x = A*(1+a1*E)*sin(w*(1+a2*E)*t+y)+ a3*E;

%# compute bins
nbins = length(x);
binEdges = linspace(min(x),max(x),nbins+1);
aj = binEdges(1:end-1);     %# bins lower edge
bj = binEdges(2:end);       %# bins upper edge
cj = ( aj + bj ) ./ 2;      %# bins center

%# assign values to bins
[~,binIdx] = histc(x, [binEdges(1:end-1) Inf]);

%# count number of values in each bin
nj = accumarray(binIdx, 1, [nbins 1], @sum);

%# plot histogram
bar(cj,nj,'hist')
set(gca, 'XTick',binEdges, 'XLim',[binEdges(1) binEdges(end)])
xlabel('Bins'), ylabel('Counts'), title('PDF')
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Error using accumarray
Third input SZ must be a full row vector with one element for each
column of SUBS.

Error in Try1 (line 40)
nj = accumarray(binIdx, 1, [nbins 1], @sum);
```

Any ideas?? THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys I found my error. I had to transpose x in order for it to work. Thanks for looking at my question!